# Which sefiros does each seder matzah correspond to according to the Ari?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, mysticism-kabbalah, matzah, arizal

The Ari says regarding the Pesach seder, (I'm not sure of the exact source though),

"Arrange the Plate on the table by taking three matzahs and placing them one on the other: First the Israelite [the lowest matzah], on it the Levite [the second matzah], and on it the Kohen [the third matzah]. These are the three intellectual faculties, chochma, bina, da'as."

Can anyone say with certainty, which matza corresponds to which sefira?

I read about this here:
http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2546858/jewish/The-Seder-Plate-A-Microcosm-of-Your-Psyche.htm

Comment: Doesn't your question already include an answer? Top-chochma, middle-bina, bottom-da'as.

Comment: You'd like to think so but it isn't clear. Hence why I'm asking if anyone can say with certainty.

Comment: Do you mean that the article you read isn't clear? Or that you think the article might be wrong?

Comment: I think I've answered your question already but just to eradicate any doubt, yes, I believe the article isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had a friend look into this and he messaged me as follows:

> I'm not such an expert of Arizal seforim but it seems a source for this is Pri Eitz Chaim Shaar Chag Hamatzos Perek Zayin, and the top matza is chochmo, second is bina and the bottom is daas.

This would mean that the Cohen matza correspons to chochma, the Levi to bina and the Yisrael to da'as. This would seem to confirm my assertion that the source quoted in the original question is indeed unclear, perhaps even misleading.